# Comparing if-else, switch-case and Contains() for performance, readibility and reusebility

Tags: c#, performance, if-statement, switch-statement

I have this below code(this is a sample, there are many more other conditions which `Session["Yapilanislem_Popup"].ToString()`  is different.).

```
       if (Session["Yapilanislem_Popup"].ToString() == "updatemustericeki")
        {
            KayitGuncelleme();
        }

        else if (Session["Yapilanislem_Popup"].ToString() == "updatemusterisenedi")
        {
            KayitGuncelleme();
        }           

            ///

        else if (Session["Yapilanislem_Popup"].ToString() == "yenitahsilat")
        {
            YeniKayit();
            Session["Yapilanislem_Popup"] = "updatetahsilat";
            BaslikLabel.Text = "Tahsilat Güncelle";
        }
        else if (Session["Yapilanislem_Popup"].ToString() == "yeniodeme")
        {
            YeniKayit();
            Session["Yapilanislem_Popup"] = "updateodeme";
            BaslikLabel.Text = "Ödeme Güncelle";
        }
```

I want to refactor this code by using a `switch-case` or `Contains()` or `switch-case` and `Contains()`.

For `Contains()` I think I can do this:

```
if (Session["Yapilanislem_Popup"].ToString().Contains("update"))
            {
                KayitGuncelleme();
            }
else if(Session["Yapilanislem_Popup"].ToString().Contains("yeni")){
YeniKayit();
                Session["Yapilanislem_Popup"] = "updateodeme";
                BaslikLabel.Text = "Ödeme Güncelle";

}
```

For `switch-case` I can basically write it for each case.

`Switch-case` would be many lines of codes for more conditions of `Session["Yapilanislem_Popup"].ToString()` however if I use `Contains()` there will be lesser number of lines of codes.

I am also concerned about performance issue.

Which one would be better to use regarding performance, readibility and reusability?

Comment: Perhaps you could mention the programming language, otherwise commenting on the performance might be difficult :-)

Comment: @Frank sorry Mr.Schmitt it's C# I tagged it, I thought it was obvious.

Comment: best performance plus (and readability too) would be creating varibale that will containt Session["Yapilanislem_Popup"].ToString() instead of calling it many times

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Massive first step, stop doing `Session["Yapilanislem_Popup"].ToString()` each time, get it once:

```
string yapPopup = Session["Yapilanislem_Popup"].ToString();
```

Then use a case statement:

```
string nextState = yapPopup; // default to no state change

switch (yapPopup)
{
case "yenitahsilat":
    YeniKayit();
    nextState = "updatetahsilat";
    BaslikLabel.Text = "Tahsilat Güncelle";
    break;

case "yeniodeme":
    YeniKayit();
    nextState = "updateodeme";
    BaslikLabel.Text = "Ödeme Güncelle";
    break;

default:
    if (yapPopup.Contains("update"))
    {
        KayitGuncelleme();
    }
    break;
}

Session["Yapilanislem_Popup"] = nextState;
```

Note that exact matches get their own `case`, any other logic/testing happens in the `default` case.

Edit: "It looks like you're writing a state machine" (ala clippy).  See use of `nextState` variable to make it more obvious.

Comment: ok thanks, and what about switch-case and Contains() comparison, any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean?  The `Contains` is in the `default` case?

Comment: Yes, thanks I didn't see that at first.Thank you this looks like a great solution.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't help noticing, it is always better to use `Convert.ToString(session["value"])` instead of `Session["Value"].ToString()` as it will handle your null objects as well.

Comment: Thank you Mr.Menon, I think it is guaranteed that it won't be null but I will use this method.